# Get last group of text from read line, with changing text?

Tags: java

I'm still very new to Java, and I'm attempting to get used to the language by jumping in and starting a big project, so I'm not surprised if I'm missing the obvious. I saw somewhere that there's a homework tag, but this semi-personal.

I'm trying to write some code that will allow me to skip over two number groupings when reading from a file line and getting the third grouping, but the first two also have a letter prefixed to them, like this: `T12345 / S6543 / 23456`. I would attempt to get only `23456`. The numbers can be assumed to be random, with any amount of digits (6 being the safe maximum), but the first group will always have a "T", the second an "S", and the third will have no prefix.

Is there a way to cut everything before the second / ? Maybe even replace everything up to the second / with spaces then `.trim()`? I obviously can't do a string search since the numbers can change, so at this point I'm stumped. Is there specific method(s) to use for something like this?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
`yourstring.split("/")[2]` this will return the third element splitted by a /

Comment: Thanks! This led me to a site that gave me almost an exact example for what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user5429501 you're welcome, but be careful, your question is very simply and there is much doc about it